# Most Recent Notes & Attachments in Formula

Tags: formula-field

I am currently using this formula in a checkbox field:

```
(TODAY() - LastActivityDate) <= 30
```

Is it possible to do this with the Notes & Attachments related list?

Would it be:

```
(TODAY() - NotesAndAttachments) <= 30
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: If a note or an attachment has been posted then I would like for the check box to be checked if it is less than or equal to 30 days

Comment: I ended up using something else

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to learning [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) (free managed package written by @AndrewFawcett), you can get the data you need without writing a single trigger or batch. An example of how to do so is included below:

- Parent Object - e.g. `Account`
- Relationship Name - `ParentId`
- Child Object - `Attachment` (and a separate rollup for `Note`)
- Field To Aggregate - `CreatedDate`
- Field To Order By - `CreatedDate` (won't work without this part)
- Aggregate Operation - `Last` (most recent, whereas `First` would be least recent)
- Aggregate Result Field - e.g. `Most_Recent_Attachment__c`

[image: Parent Object:Account;Relationship Field:ParentId;Child Object:Attachment;]

Not sure if you can roll them both up to the same field, or if you will have to roll them up separately and then use a third formula for the checkbox. Your formula will then look like:

```
OR(
    NOW() - Most_Recent_Attachment__c <= 30,
    NOW() - Most_Recent_Note__c <= 30
)
```

You can calculate the most recent value for all records in your org by hitting the `Calculate` button on the `Lookup Rollup Summary` detail page.

[image: Calculate Button]

Answer (score 0):

Standard Salesforce functionality does not allow any modification to Note and Attachment object.

Best Approach to create Attachment trigger can be: Create trigger from Developer console.

You need to click New -> Apex Trigger -> Then you can select SObject as "Attachment" from dropdown.

A trigger can be written on Attachment using Force.com IDE.

A sample code would be:

```
trigger mostRecent on Attachment (after insert) {

List<Account> parentList = new List<Account>();
for(Attachment att: Trigger.new){
   //check for object for which you want this condtion
   if(String.valueOf(att.parentId).substring(0,3) == '001')
   {
     Account acc = new Account(id=att.parentId);
     parentId.fieldname__c = system.today();
     parentList.add(acc);
   }

}

update parentList;

}
```

Once you have that value filled you can create your formula to calculate most recent logic.

Comment: What about delete case? Also why not use `Schema` comparison to get `sObjectType`?

Comment: ANT? Did you mean Developer Console?

Comment: @crop1645 I think Himanshu mean this - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/

Comment: @crop1645 sorry I fall in sleep so couldn't reply early.. I took reference from here. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181538&language=en_US and now I realized Ant should not be there :)